# DNN 8 website and a existing webapi how can I work properly?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN website and also a WebAPi.
In the past both wasn't related.
I'm finding a way to do something that related them.
Such as getting all users in DNN website,Create a user,Change password via WebAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNN has its own implementation of WebAPI allowing you to create extensions that are then exposed with WebAPI.

The implementation of this process is more complicated than can be answered in a simple StackOverflow post, but the [DNN Wiki Information](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/services-framework-webapi) should help get you going.  Once you get going you can ask more specific questions here.

Comment: Thank for your description tell me where should I go to getting started.
It would help me a lot.